# lim sup of weighted average in the tail $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider the sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,....$, and define $S_n = X_1+X_2+...+X_n$. Suppose $\mathcal{T}$ is the tail $\sigma$-algebra of $X_n$s. Prove that
$$
\{\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} S_n/C_n > a \} \in \mathcal{T},
$$
where $C_n \to \infty$.

I appreciate any comment/response.

> **My non-rigorous attempt:** To show that this event is in $\mathcal{T}$,
> I want to argue that changing a finite number of random variables will
> not affect the event. This makes sense for example when $C_n = n$, since
> $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} S_n/n$ is the limiting average which does
> not depend on a finite number of random variables. I think $S_n/C_n$
> can be thought of a weighted average, so we can argue similarly. However, I am trying to prove this rigorously.

Answer (score 4):

$(\lim \sup \frac {S_n} {C_n}>a)= (\lim \sup \frac {X_k+X_{k+1}+...+X_n} {C_n}>a)$ for any $k$ since $\frac {X_1+X_2+..+X_{k-1}} {C_n} \to 0$. From this it is clear that $(\lim \sup \frac {S_n} {C_n}>a)$ belongs to $\sigma (X_k,X_{k+1},...)$ for each $k$ and hence it belongs to $\mathcal T$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for the answer.